# How to position div within div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to place a div within the top right corner of another div :

https://plnkr.co/edit/zhZdWf4KJZU02XF8zAjG?p=preview

But I need to explicitly set the size of the div to width 600px within style "textAreaStyle" in order to place it :

[image]

Can the "Select All" be aligned within top corner of div without explicitly setting width ?

```js
function selectAll(element) {
    var doc = document
        , text = doc.getElementById(element)
        , range, selection
        ;    
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
           range = document.body.createTextRange();
           range.moveToElementText(text);
           range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
           selection = window.getSelection();        
           range = document.createRange();
           range.selectNodeContents(text);
           selection.removeAllRanges();
           selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
    
document.onclick = function(e) {    
    if (e.target.className === 'click') {
           SelectText('selectme');
    }
};
```

```css
.topcorner{
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      right:0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width:1px;
      border-color:lightgray;
}
      
.textAreaStyle {
      width: 600px;
      height: 150px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width:1px;
      border-color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br></br><br></br><br></br>
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div onclick="selectAll('preview')" class="topcorner">Select All</div>
    <div class="textAreaStyle" contenteditable id="preview">
        test text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try putting the 'select-all' div inside textAreaStyle div, and set textAreaStyle as position: relative

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/zhZdWf4KJZU02XF8zAjG?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the class to contenteditable div, add the class to it's parent. This will apply the `width` and `height` to the container element, the elements inside it will inherit these properties, thus are set relative to the contenteditable div.

[**Updated Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/BO18zgUz28cerg1pzDhu?p=preview)

```js
function selectAll(element) {
  var doc = document,
    text = doc.getElementById(element),
    range, selection;
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(text);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(text);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}

document.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'click') {
    SelectText('selectme');
  }
};
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.topcorner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
.textAreaStyle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="textAreaStyle" style="position:relative;">

  <div onclick="selectAll('preview')" class="topcorner">Select All</div>

  <div contenteditable id="preview">
    test text
  </div>

</div>
```

---

As suggested by [I Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5546445), `float: right` can also be used instead of positioning the element and applying `top` and `right` of zero on it. This will also prevent the text to go behind the *Select All* div.

```js
function selectAll(element) {
  var doc = document,
    text = doc.getElementById(element),
    range, selection;
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(text);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(text);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}

document.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'click') {
    SelectText('selectme');
  }
};
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.topcorner {
  float: right;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
.textAreaStyle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="textAreaStyle" style="position:relative;">

  <div onclick="selectAll('preview')" class="topcorner">Select All</div>

  <div contenteditable id="preview">
    test text
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I was going to write a new answer but yours is practically identical to mine! Can I suggest one update which is to use `float: right` instead of `position: absolute; top: 0; right:0;`? It's both cleaner and it will prevent text from writing underneath the "select all" button (fill the box with "text text text ..." to see what I mean).

Comment: @IStanley Thank you very much! I didn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
<div class="textAreaStyle" contenteditable id="preview">
  <div onclick="selectAll('preview')" class="topcorner">Select All</div>
  test text
</div>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
 .topcorner{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width:1px;
   border-color:lightgray;
  }

.textAreaStyle {
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:lightgray;
  position:relative; /* Added */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change markup and CSS a little bit:

```
.topcorner{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:-1px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width:1px;
   border-color:lightgray;
  }

  .textAreaStyle {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:lightgray;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Markup

```
<div class="textAreaStyle" contenteditable id="preview">
        <div onclick="selectAll('preview')" class="topcorner">Select All</div>
        test text
</div>
```

So you set parent to position: relative and width to fx. 50%. And then set the newly re-arranged select all button to position: absolute (and move it -1px because of border).

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned you want the Select All to be placed at the top right corner of the textarea; it can be achieved by doing the following

- Removing position styling for `div.topcorner`
- Moving the Select All div inside the `div.textAreaStyle`.
- Floating the `div.topcorner` to the right

```css
.topcorner {
  float: right;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
.textAreaStyle {
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div class="textAreaStyle" contenteditable id="preview">
    <div onclick="selectAll('preview')" class="topcorner">Select All</div>
    test text
  </div>
</div>
```